# Finding a DOM node in the subtree of a node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have HTML with something like

```
<div class="foo">
<h1>foo 1</h1>
..</div>

<div class="foo">
<h1>foo 2</h1>
..</div>
```

Finding the div nodes using getElementsByTagName('div') is not a problem.

While iterating of the div nodes I need to find the first H1 inside the subtree of the DIV
nodes. Is there something like getElementByTagName() on a DOM node?

Comment: Or: `document.querySelectorAll('div.foo > h1')`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Using `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` might be a bit better if he only needs the first matching node.

Comment: @CD The OP is iterating over the DIV nodes and for each iteration he needs the H1 element - therefore he needs all H1 elements.

Comment: @Šime: Yes, you are absolutely correct. In the OPs case he is already iterating over the parent divs in which case he could also call querySelector on the div nodes. My mistake for not including that in the comment.

Comment: @CD Aha, you meant `div.querySelector('h1')` on each iteration. Yes, that's a great idea. I like that more than the accepted solution ([although it's slower](http://jsperf.com/queryselector-vs-getelementsbytagname-0)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Use array notation to get the first element found:

```
var firstHeading = div.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
```

**Edit** If you were asking if you could use `getElementsByTagName` on nodes other than the `document`, yes you can.  All DOM element nodes plus the `document` node have the `getElementsByTagName` method.

Comment: I think he was actually asking if you could call .getElementsByTagName on things other than document, like div in your example. At least, I think he was?

Comment: @Robert: The OP was asking if there was a getElementByTagName (singular) method for DOM elements.

Comment: @RestRisiko That typo likely resulted in an error being thrown in the browser. You didn't check?

Comment: Not all DOM nodes, but all DOM Element nodes + the document object.